# My functions are not executing even when I call them

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am building a very simple code (I'm a beginner, just getting down the basics of python), it calculates pay by multiplying the rate by hours (both inputed by the user).

I have already succeeded with copying and pasting the same code over and over (the output runs as expected). I tried to reduce efforts by putting the code over functions to kind of simplify a shorten the script. Yet, when I do that, everything seems to go downhill. The input is asked and received, but when the function that determines errors and floats numerical input is supposed to run, it doesn't.

```
#computation of final pay

def compute_pay(hrs,rte):
    pay = hrs*rte
    print(pay)


#computation of hours; it's pretty much the same for rate; only variables #change

hrs = input("Enter Hours: ")

def compute_hours(hrs):
    try:
        float(hrs)
    except:
        hrs = -1

compute_hours(hrs)

if hrs == -1:
    print(error_m)

while hrs == -1:
    compute_hours(hrs)
    if hrs == -1:
        print(error_m)



#end

compute_pay(hrs,rte)
```

I expected the computation of the actual pay, yet I got a type error because, ​in the #end, the multiplication is made between strings, not numerical values of the variables 'hrs' and 'rte'. This happens not because I didn't establish the type of variables, but because the function containing it did not run.

Comment: Your functions *are* executing, they just don't do anything useful.

Comment: The `while` loop never asks for a new value of `hrs`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `return` statement to your function to capture output:

```
def compute_hours(hrs):
    try:
        float(hrs)
    except:
        hrs = -1
    finally:
        return hrs

new_hrs = compute_hours(hrs)
```

`new_hrs` will then store the output from `compute_hours`

Comment: It gives me an error: 'code' name 'compute_hours' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

`float(hrs)` doesn't change the value of `hrs`. It converts the value to a float, but doesn't do anything with that value. You need to return the value.

```
def compute_hours(hrs):
    try:
        return float(hrs)
    except:
        return -1
```

Then you use it like this:

```
hrs = compute_hours(hrs)
```

But if the user enters an invalid number for hours, you never ask for a new value, so your loop will be infinite. You need to prompt again.

```
while hrs == -1:
    compute_hours(hrs)
    if hrs == -1:
        print(error_m)
        hrs = input("Enter hourse: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your functions lack `return` statements, so you won't get anything useful back from `compute_hours`. It seems what you want is a function that asks the user for hours, returning -1 if they give you a bad value.

```
def get_hours_from_user():
    try:
        return float(input('Enter Hours: '))
    except ValueError:
        return -1
```

Compute pay makes more sense as a function that takes hours and rate and returns the pay (no need to abbreviate, this just makes it harder to read).

```
def compute_pay(hours, rate):
    return hours * rate
```

You can simplify the error checking a lot, though you might be better off putting this logic inside of `get_hours_from_user`

```
hours = get_hours_from_user()
while hours == -1:
    print('invalid value for hours')
    hours = get_hours_from_user()
```

Your call at the bottom to `compute_pay` uses some variable `rte`, which doesn't exist anywhere in your original code, I am adding a constant for it here:

```
RATE = 8.0
pay = compute_pay(hours, RATE)
print('Your pay is:', pay)
```